# hornetq JMSException: access denied

Tags: java, access-denied, hornetq, consumer

I'm trying to consume hornetq messages but I get this generic exception:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission getClassLoader)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.getContextClassLoader(Unknown Source)
```

on this line:

```
ObjectMessage receivedMessage = (ObjectMessage) consumer.receive();
```

I can access to this hornetq server from other client, so I deduce that my hornetq is well configured.

Answer (score 0):

You are running on a sandbox and you don't have the permission to perform the classLoading require by the ObjectMessage. Try relaxing the settings of your JVM's security sandbox, or sign the jar. Anyways it's not really a HornetQ issue. it's more a JVM security configuration thing.